# Custom function not returning correct value

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, macos, function

I have a code to create my own function but it gives me a warning:

- Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'SMUserKey *' (aka 'unsigned long *') from 'int'
- Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'SMUserKey' (aka 'unsigned long') to parameter of type 'SMUserKey *' (aka 'unsigned long *')

So it's showing warning and I want to get rid of them.

This is my .h code:

```
typedef NSUInteger SMUserKey;


NS_ENUM(SMUserKey) {
    SMUsername = 1,
    SMFirstName = 2,
    SMLastName = 3,
    SMFullName = 4,
    SMEmail = 5,
};
```

This is my .m code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *result = [SMUser getValueForKey:SMUsername];
    NSLog(@"THE RESULT: %@", result);
}

+ (NSString *)getValueForKey:(SMUserKey*)myUserKey {
    NSString *myUserKeyValue = nil;
    if (myUserKey == 1) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Username";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 2) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"First Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 3) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Last Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 4) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Full Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 5) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Email";
    }
    return myUserKeyValue;
}
```

This is the image showing the warnings:

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMob.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enum names.  **Use Them**

```
+ (NSString *)getValueForKey:(SMUserKey)myUserKey {
    switch(myUserKey) {
    case SMUsername:  return @"Username";
    case SMFirstName: return @"First Name";
    case SMLastName:  return @"Last Name";
    case SMFullName:  return @"Full Name";
    case SMEmail:     return @"EMail";
    default:          return nil;
    }
}
```

Hard coding your magic numbers is going to cause maintenance headaches long term.

Note that the parameter type should be `SMUserKey` not `SMUserKey*`

Answer (score 1):

The condition checking should be `if (myUserKey == 1)` instead of `(myUserKey = 1)`, the same modification for the rest.

Comment: Okey, thank you . It works. But now i still have the warnings. Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the warning this time?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga5zcagk85m9jy3/Schermafbeelding%202016-06-15%20om%2019.17.25.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga5zcagk85m9jy3/Schermafbeelding%202016-06-15%20om%2019.17.25.png?dl=0

Comment: i was able to fix the warning of the function , but not when I call the function

    NSString *myUserKeyValue = nil;
    
    if ((int)myUserKey == 1) {
        myUserKeyValue = usernameValue;
    }
    else if ((int)myUserKey == 2) {
        myUserKeyValue = firstnameValue;
    }
    else if ((int)myUserKey == 3) {
        myUserKeyValue = lastnameValue;
    }
    else if ((int)myUserKey == 4) {
        myUserKeyValue = fullnameValue;
    }
    else if ((int)myUserKey == 5) {
        myUserKeyValue = emailValue;
    }
    return myUserKeyValue;

Answer (score 1):

Just posting another way of doing this using switch case,

```
+ (NSString *)getValueForKey:(SMUserKey*)myUserKey {
NSString *myUserKeyValue = nil;

switch (SMUserKey) {
    case 1:
    {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Username";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        myUserKeyValue = @"First Name";
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Last Name";
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Full Name";
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Email";
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}

return myUserKeyValue;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *result = [SMUser getValueForKey:SMUsername];
    NSLog(@"THE RESULT: %@", result);
}

+ (NSString *)getValueForKey:(SMUserKey*)myUserKey {
    NSString *myUserKeyValue = nil;
    if (myUserKey == 1) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Username";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 2) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"First Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 3) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Last Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 4) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Full Name";
    }
    if (myUserKey == 5) {
        myUserKeyValue = @"Email";
    }
    return myUserKeyValue;
}
```

Comment: No! You're type casting NSUInteger to pointers, and then comparing a pointer to a hard coded number. Fix your parameter type.